# Showing input parameter on same page in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

I am trying to show the results on the same page as the form in Thymleaf and Spring and this is what I have tried till now:

Controller:

```
   @Controller
public class ThymeleafController {
    
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String getHello() {
        return "hello";
    }
    
    
    @PostMapping("/test")
    public String test(@RequestParam("text1")String str, Model model) {
        
        model.addAttribute("sample", str);
        
        return "test";
    }
    
}
```

test.html page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th ="http://www.thymeleaf.org" >
<head>
<meta charset ="UTF-8" ></meta>
<title> Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Hello World</h1>
<form method ="post" action ="/test" >
Enter: <input type ="text" name ="text1" />
<input type ="submit" value ="click" />
</form>
<span th:text ="${sample == null} ? 'null' : ${sample}" ></span>
</body>
</html>
```

When i go on test page i see this error:

```
  There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
```

Can someone give me an ideea or an example how I could display a value on the same page as the form / input ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref : https://hellokoding.com/handling-form-submission-example-with-java-spring-boot-and-freemarker/

Add for get , so this issue will get solved.

```
@Controller
public class ThymeleafController {
    
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String getHello() {
        return "hello";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String testfrm() {
        return "test";
    }

    @PostMapping("/test")
    public String test(@RequestParam("text1")String str, Model model) {
        
        return "test";
    }
    
}
```